# Incrementally trainable one class classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I'm working on a classification problem where I have data about only One Class, so I wanna classify between that "Target"class against all other possibilities which is the "Outlier" Class in incremental learning. So, I have found some libraries, but none of them support updating classifier.

Do you know any library that supports one-class classifier with updating pre-existed classifier especially in java or matlab?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any full pre-existing solution to your question. However, I can suggest two approaches:

1. Neural networks have been used for various types of anomaly detection (e.g. see [here](http://www-ist.massey.ac.nz/smarsland/PUBS/NCS.pdf), with the problem framed as "novelty detection"). Depending on the nature of your problem, this might be a suitable solution, as NNs can be incrementally trained and are supported by several widely used libraries. The right one to use would be highly dependent on your problem framing and the network architecture chosen.
2. Although most SVM libraries do not support incremental training, there are some with such support (e.g. see in [Can an SVM learn incrementally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967460/can-an-svm-learn-incrementally)). However, as far as I can see, none of the two libraries suggested in the cited reference supports unary classification. But  you could try basing a tailored solution on one of them (their source code seems to be freely available).

PS if you found one of these (or any other) solution to work, please post it as an answer as well :)